# python: class function returns value but isn't usable

Tags: python, list, function, class

I have a class called Stone, inside I have a function called return_coordinates(self), which returns the coordinates of a stone. When I print the coordinates I can see them perfectly but when I try to use them, it prints the error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Here's the class:

```
class Stone:
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        self.image = image
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw_stone(self):
        image = pygame.image.load(self.image)
        screen.blit(image, (self.x, self.y))

    def return_id(self):
        return self.image.replace("image", "").replace(".png", "")

    def return_coordinates(self):
        return [self.x, self.y]
```

Now I have created some class Stone objects and stored them in a list. When I access the object in a list and try to use its function return_coordinates(), it prints the error.

Here's the code:

```
if draw_selected == True:
    coordinates = selected[3].return_coordinates()
    selection_box = pygame.rect(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], 57, 80)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [21, 146, 146], selection_box, 2)
```

if i print the coordinates then it prints a list with numerical values just like it's supposed to but when I want to access a specific coordinate inside the list like coordinates[0], then I get the error. All the code is inside the same file.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\tech\project_m\mahjong.py", line 198, in <module>
selection_box = pygame.rect(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], 57, 80)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please create a [mre] showing the full error message.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pygame.Rect` with capital `R`?

Comment: `rect` is the C module that implements Rect objects.

Comment: Okay, I had a typo in my code. It should have been pygame.Rect instead of pygame.rect. Thank you iamvegan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that Python is a case-sensitive language. Your code works with `pygame.Rect`:

```
if draw_selected == True:
    coordinates = selected[3].return_coordinates()
    selection_box = pygame.Rect(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], 57, 80)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [21, 146, 146], selection_box, 2)
```